# amcharts change fill color for array of IDs

Tags: javascript, amcharts4

While [the documentation for amcharts4](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/chart-types/map/#Map_series)  provides an indication for filling polygons with colors:

```
chart.backgroundSeries.mapPolygons.template.polygon.fill = am4core.color("#aadaff");
```

It is not readily obvious how one could have alternate colours operating with sets of preloaded data.  Assuming for a set of country polygons:

```
black_filled_polygon.ids =  ["BR", "CA", "CN", "HR", "DK"]
pink_filled_polygon.ids =  ["NO", "PH", "PL", "PT", "ZA"]
```

how can these be defined to interact with `am4core`, possibly as a seperate variable defining script in order to refactor code cleanly, and generate a distinct fill color?

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't have to color the `polygon` of a `MapPolygon`, just the `MapPolygon` or the series' template itself, i.e. instead of

```js
chart.backgroundSeries.mapPolygons.template.polygon.fill = am4core.color("#aadaff");
```

you would do (note the missing `.polygon`):

```js
chart.backgroundSeries.mapPolygons.template.fill = am4core.color("#aadaff");
```

(not sure why `backgroundSeries` is set as a property of `chart`?)

You can map colors to polygon IDs via [binding property fields to fields in data](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/chart-types/map/#Binding_properties_to_data), e.g.

```js
var black_filled_polygon_ids =  ["BR", "CA", "CN", "HR", "DK"]
var pink_filled_polygon_ids =  ["NO", "PH", "PL", "PT", "ZA"]
var data = [];


black_filled_polygon_ids.map(function(id) {
  data.push( {
    id: id,
    color: "black"
  });
});
pink_filled_polygon_ids.map(function(id) {
  data.push( {
    id: id,
    color: "pink"
  });
});

polygonTemplate.propertyFields.fill = "color";
polygonSeries.data = data;
```

Here's a demo:

https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/062babaa4fec26c87c74c8dd5a885e42